# Entity Framework is too slow during mapping data up to 100k

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have min 100 000 data into a `Job_Details` table and I'm using Entity Framework to map the data.

This is the code:

```
public GetJobsResponse GetImportJobs()
{
    GetJobsResponse getJobResponse = new GetJobsResponse();
    List<JobBO> lstJobs = new List<JobBO>();

    using (NSEXIM_V2Entities dbContext = new NSEXIM_V2Entities())
    {
        var lstJob = dbContext.Job_Details.ToList();

        foreach (var dbJob in lstJob.Where(ie => ie.IMP_EXP == "I" && ie.Job_No != null))
        {
            JobBO job = MapBEJobforSearchObj(dbJob);
            lstJobs.Add(job);
        }
    }

    getJobResponse.Jobs = lstJobs;

    return getJobResponse;
}
```

I found to this line is taking about 2-3 min to execute

```
var lstJob = dbContext.Job_Details.ToList();
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To outline the performance issues with your example: (see inline comments)

```
public GetJobsResponse GetImportJobs()
{
    GetJobsResponse getJobResponse = new GetJobsResponse();
    List<JobBO> lstJobs = new List<JobBO>();

    using (NSEXIM_V2Entities dbContext = new NSEXIM_V2Entities())
    {
        // Loads *ALL* entities into memory. This effectively takes all fields for all rows across from the database to your app server. (Even though you don't want it all)
        var lstJob = dbContext.Job_Details.ToList(); 

        // Filters from the data in memory.
        foreach (var dbJob in lstJob.Where(ie => ie.IMP_EXP == "I" && ie.Job_No != null))
        {
        // Maps the entity to a DTO and adds it to the return collection.
            JobBO job = MapBEJobforSearchObj(dbJob);
            lstJobs.Add(job);
        }
    }
    // Returns the DTOs.
    getJobResponse.Jobs = lstJobs;

    return getJobResponse;
}
```

First: pass your WHERE clause to EF to pass to the DB server rather than loading all entities into memory..

```
public GetJobsResponse GetImportJobs()
{
    GetJobsResponse getJobResponse = new GetJobsResponse();

    using (NSEXIM_V2Entities dbContext = new NSEXIM_V2Entities())
    {
        // Will pass the where expression to be DB server to be executed. Note: No .ToList() yet to leave this as IQueryable.
        var jobs = dbContext.Job_Details..Where(ie => ie.IMP_EXP == "I" && ie.Job_No != null));
```

Next, use SELECT to load your DTOs. Typically these won't contain as much data as the main entity, and so long as you're working with IQueryable you can load related data as needed. Again this will be sent to the DB Server so you cannot use functions like "MapBEJobForSearchObj" here because the DB server does not know this function. You can SELECT a simple DTO object, or an anonymous type to pass to a dynamic mapper.

```
    var dtos = jobs.Select(ie => new JobBO
       {
          JobId = ie.JobId,
          // ... populate remaining DTO fields here.
       }).ToList();
    getJobResponse.Jobs = dtos;

    return getJobResponse;
}
```

Moving the .ToList() to the end will materialize the data into your JobBO DTOs/ViewModels, pulling just enough data from the server to populate the desired rows and with the desired fields.

In cases where you may have a large amount of data, you should also consider supporting server-side pagination where you pass a page # and page size, then utilize a .Skip() + .Take() to load a single page of entries at a time.